# Check if a point falls inside a geofence?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-location, geofencing

Is it possible to check if a given latitude and longitude falls inside of a given GeoFence using iOS 5 APIs? How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is yes:

```
CLRegion *region = your geofence;
CLLocationCoordinate2D myLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(38.9, -77.04);
if ([region containsCoordinate:myLocation]) {
   NSLog(@"You're soaking in it.");
}
```

Note that only circular regions ("fences") are currently supported.  See the [*Location Awareness Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW15) and the [*CLRegion Class Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLRegion_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I guess containsCoordinate is deprecated and most of the syntax has been changed.